# Authentication/Authorization mechanism for microservices

Tags: authentication, authorization, microservices

I have project with many micro services each one doing its job. One of them responsible for authentication and authorization. But its not clear how other services should check users permissions. Is there any mechanism to deal with this task?

Answer (score 2):

One of the best approaches is the **OAuth** delegation protocol with JSON token **JWT**

[Authentication in micro-services architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpHKm.png)

1. the user send his credentials to the OAuth server
2. The server Checks the user's information (from LDAP server for example), then gives him an access token
3. the user send his request with the access token to the API Gateway
4. the API Gateway extracts out the access_token from the request, then he will talks to the Token Exchange endpoint to validate it and then issues a JWT
5. this JWT That contains all the necessarily information about the user will be sent to the micro-service.
6. the micro-service also should verify the validity of the token by talking to the token exchange endpoint.
7. when the token is checked, the micro-service can start its job.

I think this link will be useful for you [Securing Microservices](https://medium.facilelogin.com/securing-microservices-with-oauth-2-0-jwt-and-xacml-d03770a9a838)

Answer (score 1):

You said that this responsibility belongs to a microservice. So, the other microservices don't check permissions, they delegate.

If you use an API Gateway and the other microservices are not accessible from the outside then it calls the authentication/authorisation microservice before forwarding the request to the upstream microservice.

If you don't use an API Gateway then each microservice call the authentication/authorisation microservice before actually performing the action.

Comment: In the second case each service depends from Authorization service, Is this a good idea?

Comment: @Vigen I don't see how you could do in other way. The auth MS owns the auth domain. For better resilience (avoid cascade failures) you could use a cached result in case of authMS failure.